# Want to know about a creature which bite me

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, invertebrates

[image]

I am Sachin from MP India. Few minutes back I have gotten bite by a creature. What is its name? Is it harmful if I got bitten by it? Feeling little pain there.

Comment: Hi Sachin, welcome to Biology.SE! Please review our [help] page and our [species-identification guidelines](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info). You must include the specimen size or some approximation of it. Also, the more specific you are about your location the better -- 2 things: 1) is "MP" Madhya Pradesh? and 2) what kind of habitat did you find this in? (urban, forest, mountain, aquatic, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

That is an insect, in the order Zygentoma. These are harmless, and do not bite. If you were bitten by something, it was not this?

Comment: Who is "we". I find long-winded, padded answers extremely annoying when all the person wants to know it whether a bug can hurt them. Go ahead and remove it. I answered the question.